# PHP: Check to see if all the values in an array are less than x

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function to do this?

For example if I have an array like 1,1,3,2,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,5,1
The function should return true if and only if all the numbers in the array are less than 5

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
if(max($yourArray) < 5) {
  //all values in array are less than 5
}
```

Comment: Nice one, without resorting to array_map.

Comment: I knew this was possible another way, but I knew php had a function to make this easy. Just what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

`array_map` that everyone is suggesting is of not much use here. `array_reduce` would be:

```
array_reduce($array, function ($v, $a) { return $v && $a < 5; }, true)
```

But @Mchl's use of `max` is of course best.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_filter` to run a command over each argument, and ensure that the list is empty, like so:

```
function greater_than_four($num) {
    return (int)$num > 4;
}

if( array_filter($list, "greater_than_four") ) {
    // INVALID
} else {
    // VALID
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't create your own function?

```
function allunder5(yourarray) {
   foreach $yourarray as $yournumber {
       if ($yournumber > 5) {
          return false
       }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkArray(&$arr, $max){
    foreach($arr as $e){
       if($e>$max){
           return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mchl already gave you the most concise and elegant solution, but I spent some minutes to create an ugly one-liner solution and will post my quirky and hackish solution as a curiosity or a warning example.

```
function arrayContainsValueOverLimit($arr, $limit) {
    return ! array_reduce(
                    array_map(
                        // Closure used with array_map
                        function ($val) use (&$limit) {
                            return $val <= $limit;
                        }, 

                        // Values passed into array_map
                        $arr
                    ), 

                    // Closure used with array_reduce
                    function ($r, $v) {
                        return $r && $v;
                    }, 

                    // Starting value for array_reduce
                    true
                );
}    

var_dump(
    arrayContainsValueOverLimit(
        array(1,1,3,2,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,5,1),
        3
    )
);
```

For more info on PHP closures, consult the [Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: The obfuscation contest is next door... ;-P

Comment: @deceze: if this were a perl question, I'm sure we would have several pretty regexes for solving this problem already.