# Check if there is a bigger number than X in array

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I need a function, without looping, that checks if the array values are bigger than a number of my choice **X**. If there is, return false.

Is there a nice efficient way to do this? Maybe some anonymous function?

Comment: Did you mean the sum of the values was bigger than X?

Comment: The whole question is slighty confusing, please provide an example to make it clearer.

Comment: There is little confusion in the question. Do you want to search that whether there is any value in array which is bigger than the value of your choice or all values of array is bigger than the value of your choice?

Comment: The answers on this page look quite confused by the lack of a [mcve] in this question.  Unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [`min` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php):

```
if (min($values) > $my_value) {
    // all values are larger
}
```

You can find other solutions in this similar question: [PHP: Check to see if all the values in an array are less than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992872/php-check-to-see-if-all-the-values-in-an-array-are-less-than-x).

Comment: isnt this the opposite of the request in the question?

Comment: Not quite sure... the title seems to suggest to look for one number, while I interpret the text such that every value must be larger. I think the question needs clarification.

Comment: yeh.  either `min` or `max` should do it either way...  unless he wants a summation...  hmmm

Answer (score 1):

you can make this into an anon function...

```
function is_bigger($x,$arry){
    if(max($arry) > $x){
        return false;
    }
}
```

or as anon function...

```
$res = function($x,$arry){
    if(max($arry) > $x){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```